# FutureBuilder not updating my data inside listview

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using Futurebuilder to update my profile data but it is not showing new products added until I restart my app.

```
FutureBuilder(
                    future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('posts')
                        .where('uid', isEqualTo: widget.uid)
                        .get(),
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                      }
                      return GridView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 3,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 5,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 2,
                          childAspectRatio: 1,
                        ),
                        ........
```

Comment: Never define the Future in the future: parameter of a FutureBuilder.  Instead, lift it out as State and use initState to initialize it, as illustrated in my video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FutureBuilder is basically used to get data once your app is built. It does not provide you with continuous updates of data until you rebuild your app. To get continuous data you can use StreamBuilder. For more information, you can go through the flutter documentation.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html

Here is the code that will help you out.

```
StreamBuilder(
                    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('posts')
                        .where('uid', isEqualTo: widget.uid)
                        .snapshot(),
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                      }
                      return GridView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 3,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 5,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 2,
                          childAspectRatio: 1,
                        ),
                        ........
```

Comment: Never define the stream in the stream: parameter of a streambuilder.  Instead, lift it out as State and initialize it in setState.  For details, see my video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg.

Comment: Thanks! it is working perfectly. I will go through the documentation for more detailed information.